# For a multi-line prompt, is there any downside to printing the first line vs inluding in the PS1 string?

Tags: bash

Basically, having the PS1 prompt set like this

(Assume all varibles and functions escape properly)

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='\
ret=$?;\
p_colorSetup;\
PS1="[\[${P_TIME}\]\A\[${P_RES}\]]$(p_multiPlex)[\[${P_NAME}\]\u\[${P_RES}\]@\[${P_HOST}\]\h\[${P_RES}\]]: \[${P_DIR}\]\w\[${P_RES}\]\n$(p_returnColor ${ret}) \\$ "'
```

vs doing this

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='\
ret=$?;\
p_colorSetup;\
printf "%b" "[${P_TIME}$(date +%H:%M)${P_RES}]$(p_multiPlex)[${P_NAME}$(id -un)${P_RES}@${P_HOST}$(hostname -s)${P_RES}]: ${P_DIR}$(pwd | sed -e "s#${HOME}#~#" )${P_RES} \n";\
PS1="$(p_returnColor ${ret}) \\$ "'
```

I'm curious if there's any benefits/drawbacks to doing it one way vs the other.  As long as I escape everything correctly, I don't seem to run into any issues with wrapping when typing or going through my history.

Is there any reason in this case to use one vs the other?

Comment: Aside: That's kind of awful. Try to avoid command substitutions in performance-sensitive code -- every `$(foo)` is a `pipe()` call, a `fork()`, a `wait()`, etc; much more efficient to have side-effecting functions (ie. ones that write their results to a variable whose name is passed as an argument). (Okay, granted, your shell prompt might not *usually* be performance-sensitive, but when you've got a system at load 90 where you're trying to find and kill the offending processes, every little source of lag can become a lot of pain).

Comment: I would define a function and call that from `PROMPT_COMMAND` rather than embedding a lot of code directly. `PROMPT_COMMAND=make_prompt`, then define `make_prompt () { ...; }` accordingly.

Comment: @chepner since that would still have to run every time would there be any actual difference between the two?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Could you elaborate on what you mean by the functions.  I'm not quite familiar with some of those terms, or how you'd use that in bash if I'm understanding the meaning correctly.

Comment: @Trel, those are the OS-level calls that bash has to make whenever you use command substitution syntax. `fork()`, in particular, is relatively expensive, *especially* if you're using common bash-for-Windows builds. Point being that it's best to avoid unnecessary command substitutions in code that's called repeatedly and expected to be fast.

Comment: @Trel There's no performance difference; it just makes it a lot easier to read, as the quoting is far simpler.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what would be the best alternative to dynamically include that information in the prompt?

Comment: @Trel, so, for `timevar=$(date ...)` bash has `printf -v timevar '%(%H:%M)T' -1` in current releases as a modern replacement, which will be far faster to execute, and then you can use `"$timevar"` in your string.

Comment: @Trel, ...for `id -un`, just use `$USER` -- that's what it's there for -- or of course `\u`.

Comment: @Trel, ...for `p_multiPlex`, depends on what it is, but if you can rewrite it to save its output to a variable without forking without writing to stdout, it'll be much faster.

Comment: @Trel, ...for `hostname -s`, `${HOSTNAME%%.*}`.

Comment: @Trel, ...and the silly pipeline involving running `sed` on the output of `pwd` can be replaced with a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) operating on `$PWD`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll check those variables, though the p_multiPlex needs to be a function, not a variable due to what it does.  The others I'll play around with more.

Comment: @Trel The idea is to have your function set a global variable rather than write to standard output (which needs to be captured with the command substitution).

Comment: @Trel, I'm not telling you to `p_multiPlex` can't be a function -- I'm saying it shouldn't be called in a command substitution, so any output you want to capture from it should be via use of a variable it writes. It's more efficient to first call the function in your main shell and then use the variable that it set than to call the function in a command substitution and capture its output.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy in regards to that I think I may have an idea which could work with it, though it'll need a complete re-write with how it works, but I think I have an idea how I can do it, I'll report back in a few.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, here's what I came up with: http://termbin.com/79d1 (just fyi, I'm aware of tput, but I'm intentionally not using that at this time)

Answer (score 1):

I would define a function to call from `PROMPT_COMMAND`, which makes it simpler to quote and split the code across multiple lines. This makes it easier to read, debug, and modify.

```
make_prompt () {
  ret=$?
  p_colorSetup
  PS1="[\[$P_TIME\]\A\[$P_RES\]]"
  PS1+=$(p_multiPlex)
  PS1+="[\[$P_NAME\]\u\[$P_RES\]@\[${P_HOST}\]\h\[${P_RES}\]]: "
  PS1+="\[${P_DIR}\]\w\[${P_RES}\]\n"
  PS1+=$(p_returnColor ${ret})
  PS1+=' \$'
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=make_prompt
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure, that Bash can calculate the length of the prompt, which is the number of printable characters. If you print something, Bash does not know about it. And if you edit multi-line commands, Bash will messes the prompt.

In most cases it is better to use Bash's parameter expansion instead of `sed`.

I think it is better to use PROMPT_COMMAND just to define some variables, which will be referenced in `PS1`. For readability it might be better to write a function, which builds `PS1`.

I do some fancy prompt coloring and length clipping:

```
export PS1_MAXDIRLEN=25
```

I create a function for `PROMPT_COMMAND`, which sets just some variables using Bash's parameter expansion.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND ()
{
  # Exit status
  EXIT_STATUS=$?
  PS1EXIT=${EXIT_STATUS##0}

  # Working directory
  PS1CLIP=${PWD: $((-PS1_MAXDIRLEN))}
  local p=${PS1CLIP:+${PWD: $((-(PS1_MAXDIRLEN-1)))}}
  PS1CLIP=${PS1CLIP:+<}
  PS1DIR=${p:-$PWD}
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND=PROMPT_COMMAND
```

And then I use the variables in my function, which builds `PS1`.

```
ps1 ()
{
  local bold="\[\e[1m\]"
  local black="\[\e[30m\]"
  local red="\[\e[31m\]"
  local green="\[\e[32m\]"
  local yellow="\[\e[33m\]"
  local blue="\[\e[34m\]"
  local magenta="\[\e[35m\]"
  local cyan="\[\e[36m\]"
  local reset="\[\e[m\]"

  # terminal title
  if [ "$TERM" = xterm ]; then
    echo -n '\[\e]0;\h${PS1EXIT:+ [$PS1EXIT]}\a\]'
  fi

  # visible prompt
  echo -n $bold

  # exit code
  echo -n '${PS1EXIT:+'$black'['$red'$PS1EXIT'$black'] }'

  # user @ host
  echo -n $red'\u'$black'@'$magenta'\h'$black':'

  # directory
  echo -n $red'$PS1CLIP'$blue'${PS1DIR////'$black'/'$blue'}'

  # command number
  #echo -n $black':'$yellow'\!'

  # prompt char
  echo -n $black'\$'

  # reset colors
  echo $reset' '
}

export PS1=$(ps1)

unset ps1
```

Comment: *grumble*. All-caps names are used by variables with meaning to the system or shell; POSIX [reserves](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) names with at least one lower-case character for application use. And `echo -n` is undefined behavior -- use `printf` instead, as specified in the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) And parameter expansions should be quoted -- see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: (Also, with a prompt, you have no idea what commands the user will be running, and thus what the current value of `IFS` will be -- making quoting all the more important; if `IFS='['` for some odd reason, the code here would have all manner of problems).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried `IFS='['` and it has no effect on the prompt.

Comment: That seems unlikely, since `IFS='['` will change `str="string[with[brackets"; echo $str` to instead echo `string with brackets`. Are you sure you weren't actually testing in ZSH? Regardless, pick a character that *is* present in strings you're expanding in unquoted `echo`s, and putting that character in `IFS` will break your code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is a very Bash specific question. So the `echo` will always be Bash's internal `echo`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Bash's internal `echo` changes behavior based on active shell options. Set both `posix` and `xpg_echo`, and suddenly it follows the standard to the letter -- so, for example, `echo -e` prints `-e` on output.

Comment: Going back to the failure to reproduce earlier -- alternately, I'm guessing you ran `IFS='['` *without* subsequently rerunning `PS1=$(ps1)`. Since the OP wants their PS1 to change based on time and other introspected content, one can't write a function expected to only be run *once* in the default environment/configuration, but can expect it to be re-invoked as from `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Tried it just with Bash. I tried `IFS=m` and it does not fail either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165075/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-ceving).